# Error Re-rendering Index File for Flask Application

Tags: python, flask

Trying to develop a simple Flask application to generate simple multiple-choice addition questions until ten are answered correctly by user (currently hitting a wall). Having trouble with two things:

1. Rendering the multiple choice answer options.
2. Reloading another questions once the first answer is submitted.

Any help or advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is app.py.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'  # Set a secure secret key
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'  # Store session data in the filesystem

@app.before_request
def initialize_session():
    if 'score' not in session:
        session['score'] = 0
    if 'question' not in session:
        generate_question()

def generate_question():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    correct_answer = num1 + num2
    choices = generate_choices(correct_answer)
    session['question'] = {
        'num1': num1,
        'num2': num2,
        'correct_answer': correct_answer,
        'choices': choices
    }

def generate_choices(correct_answer):
    choices = [correct_answer]
    while len(choices) < 4:
        choice = random.randint(1, 20)
        if choice not in choices:
            choices.append(choice)
    random.shuffle(choices)
    return choices

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_answer = request.form['answer']
        correct_answer = session['question']['correct_answer']
        
        if user_answer == str(correct_answer):
            session['score'] += 1
        
        if session['score'] == 10:
            result = "Congratulations! You answered 10 questions correctly."
            session['score'] = 0  # Reset the score to play again
        else:
            result = None
        
        generate_question()
        
        return render_template('index.html', result=result)
    
    question = session['question']
    num1 = question['num1']
    num2 = question['num2']
    choices = question.get('choices', [])  # Use the `get` method with a default value of an empty list
    
    return render_template('index.html', num1=num1, num2=num2, choices=choices)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Addition Problem</title>
    <style>
        /* CSS styles here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Addition Problem</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <div class="question">
                <p>What is {{ num1 }} + {{ num2 }}?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="choices">
                {% for choice in choices %}
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ choice }}">
                        {{ choice }}
                    </label>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        {% if result %}
            <div class="result">
                <h2>{{ result }}</h2>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a browser image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code, and rendering the multiple choice answer options worked right away on my machine. As for reloading the questions, you just need to pass the question values in your `index`'s POST return statement. This part:

```py
generate_question()
        
return render_template('index.html', result=result)
```

Needs to be changed to:

```py
generate_question()

question = session['question']
num1 = question['num1']
num2 = question['num2']
choices = question.get('choices', [])

return render_template('index.html', num1=num1, num2=num2, choices=choices, result=result)
```

(the same way you pass the values in your GET request)

Result:

[image: Working quiz app]